# Most suitable buffer texture format for bool data storage?

Tags: opengl, buffer, vulkan

I have seen some examples simply using the `R8Uint` format for bool data usage. But is there any other solution that's storage-saving?

Comment: The list of [valid buffer texture formats](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture#Image_formats) is not long; there aren't many to choose from. What exactly do you need our advice for?

Comment: @NicolBolas I specified my question in my other reply. If there is any insight about the performance impact of the bits packing/unpacking operations, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the smallest format is 1 byte.
Stating the obvious: Depending on your situation you could pack 8 bits (Booleans) into that byte.

Comment: True. I did read about codes that pack data into different precision formats. But haven't seen anyone doing it for booleans. So I wanted to know all the viable solutions and also whether packing/unpacking operations in a shader in such situations would compromise performance.

Comment: It is not really specific to shaders -- it is relevant to plain C++ too. Packing/unpacking one `bool` to/from bitfield costs exactly one bitwise-& (usually the fastest op there is). The smaller memory may help cache(/texture loads in shader), so it is possible you get some of the performance back in some cases.